# Pagination result with Spring Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

First of all, I'm a complete novice with Java. If I'm making a mistake, don't hesitate to correct me.

A very old project for a rest service is being reinstalled by me. I need to return a stored procedure in page form .

However, I am unable to do so because the count query is broken. Because it adds a "TOP" to the middle.

Is there a way to avoid this, or am I on the incorrect path entirely?

Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TestProcedureData {
        
        @Id 
        @Column(name="A_COLUMN")
        String aColumn;
        
        @Column(name="B_COLUMN")
        String bColumn;
        
        @Column(name="C_COLUMN")
        String cColumn;
        
        @Column(name="D_COLUMN")
        String dColumn;
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class TestProcedureServices {

    ITestProcedureData testProcedureData;

    public TestProcedureServices(ITestProcedureData testProcedureData) { 
        this.testProcedureData = testProcedureData;
    }
    
    public Page<TestProcedureData> getProcedureData(Pageable pageable){
        return testProcedureData.getProcedureData(pageable);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestProcedureControllers {
    
    private TestProcedureServices testProcedureServices;

    public TestProcedureControllers(TestProcedureServices testProcedureServices) { 
        this.testProcedureServices = testProcedureServices;
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public Page<TestProcedureData> getProcedureData(Pageable pageable){     
        return testProcedureServices.getProcedureData(pageable);
    }

}
```

Repo

```
public interface ITestProcedureData extends JpaRepository<TestProcedureData, String> {

    @Query(nativeQuery=true,value="exec sp_TEST_PROCEDURE 'param1','param2'",
           countQuery="SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE A_COLUMN=param1 AND B_COLUMN=param2")

    public Page<TestProcedureData> getProcedureData(Pageable pageable);


}
```

Request

> ```
> localhost:8080/test?size=1&page1
> ```

This was the error

> 2022-12-01 03:12:03.159 [INFO ] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 2 ms
> Hibernate: exec sp_TEST top(?)_PROCEDURE 'param1','param2'
> 2022-12-01 03:12:03.379 [WARN ] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
> 2022-12-01 03:12:03.380 [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.
> 2022-12-01 03:12:03.389 [ERROR] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.

Are the classes I have listed above correct? I appreciate it.

Procedure

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TEST_PROCEDURE]
    @param1    VARCHAR(20),
    @param2      VARCHAR(20) 
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT AQA.[A_COLUMN]
       ,AQA.[B_COLUMN]
       ,Q.NAME AS C_COLUMN
       ,A.NAME AS D_COLUMN 
   FROM [rpt_ACTIVITY] AQA, TENANT A, QUEUE Q
   WHERE Q.QID = AQA.SERVED_QID 
   AND A.AID = AQA.AID 
   AND (@param1 = '0' OR AQA.SERVED_QID IN (SELECT * FROM GET_IDS(@param1)) )
   AND (@param2 = '-1' OR (@param2 = '-2' AND A.DELETION_ORDER != 0) OR(@param2 = '0' AND A.DELETION_ORDER = 0) OR A.AID IN (select * from dbo.GET_IDS(@param2))) ORDER BY AQA.TIME
END
```

Comment: Could we have a look at your stored procedure? Also, you need to add the `param1` and `param2` in `getProcedureData`. Something like this `getProcedureData(@Param("param1") param1, ...)` and then you can use this param in your query like this `value="exec sp_TEST_PROCEDURE(:param1, :param2)`.

You can find more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures#query-annotation)

Comment: The stored procedure is as follows.
Although I agree with what you said, I now add the parameters internally rather than externally. As an illustration, I inserted param1 and param2.
The top(?) parameter in this part, "Hibernate: exec sp TEST top(?) PROCEDURE 'param1','param2'," is where I'm having the most trouble.
When I use it as a List rather than a Page, it functions.

Comment: In your `countQuery`, wrap the result in a `COUNT()` function. Like this : `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Comment: It appears like a workaround to really use `--/n #pageable /n`, which I put to the end of the stored procedure. Its disregard for the `size` and `page` parameters supplied in the request is the issue here. All the info it discovers is returned, even if I send these values.

Comment: Another option could be to pass the size and page number in your procedure and then apply an `offset` and `limit` to your query. Here is an [example](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-limit/). Your `offset` should be `size * page number` and your `limit` should be `size`. Then with the list result you can convert it into a `Page` like this : `new PageImpl<>(yourListHere, pageableFromRequest, totalElements);`

Comment: I appreciate your assistance very much, Marc. I was able to solve the problem because of your directions.

Comment: Glad it worked out, sorry I couldn't provide better answer.